# why does not "/bin/sh cd /root/eos/" work ,but "/bin/sh -c ls && cd /root/eos/" works well in centos

Tags: linux, bash

I have met a question when using cd command in a script.
here is the test below, so, could anyone help to tell the reason?

why does not "/bin/sh  cd /root/eos/" work ,but "/bin/sh -c ls &&  cd /root/eos/" works well in centos
thanks.

> ```
> [root@izbp16eo65uiwii1mfm63tz eos]# pwd
> /root/testeosnode/CryptoKylin-Testnet/docker/eos
> [root@izbp16eo65uiwii1mfm63tz eos]# /bin/sh  cd /root/eos/
> [root@izbp16eo65uiwii1mfm63tz eos]# pwd
> /root/testeosnode/CryptoKylin-Testnet/docker/eos
> [root@izbp16eo65uiwii1mfm63tz eos]# /bin/sh -c ls &&  cd /root/eos/
> build.log  build.sh  Dockerfile  eos
> [root@izbp16eo65uiwii1mfm63tz eos]# pwd
> /root/eos
> ```

env
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
[root@izbp16eo65uiwii1mfm63tz eos]# ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 10oct  9 18:00 /bin/sh -> bash

Comment: `/bin/sh  cd /root/eos/` will give you `/bin/sh: 0: Can't open cd`

Comment: It's all about the definition of "works". "Works" != "shows the expected output" – in the latter case, the problem might be the expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/bin/sh cd /root/eos/` does not work because that's not the proper way to have /bin/sh execute a command.

`/bin/sh -c ls` works because the `-c` argument will make `/bin/sh` execute the next argument, which is `ls`.

`/bin/sh  -c "cd /root/eos/"` would "work". It will run `/bin/sh` , that process will change its directory to `/root/eos` and then that process will exit, leaving the working directory of your running shell unaffected.

`/bin/sh -c ls && cd /root/eos/` is the combination of 2 commands.

First `/bin/sh -c ls` is executed. If that succeeds, `cd /root/eos` is executed. Note that the `/bin/sh` command only runs `ls`. It does not run `cd /root/eos` - that part is run by the current shell of yours, and will change your working directory.

Note that this is also different from doing:

`/bin/sh -c "ls && cd /root/eos"`

In thats case `/bin/sh` will run the entire `ls && cd /root/eos` command - though as the `cd` command only affects the process started with the `/bin/sh` command, it will not affect the shell you are running this in.